# Bootstrap-5 Border-Width Utility is not Changing Border Width

Tags: border, bootstrap-5

The following code:

```
<h2 className="p-3 border border-3">Instruments</h2>
```

should put a thick border around my h2. But it isn't. I can't produce any change in border width with any of the Bootstrap border utilities, 1 through 5.

Bootstrap is working fine everywhere else in my application. I have no custom style sheet. Only Bootstrap.

I have tried Googling this, but no luck.  Can anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: This is [not reproducible](https://codeply.com/p/iRE6YYOntV) Are you actually trying to use className instead of class?

Comment: I am working in React

Comment: Yeah makes sense, but still it's not reproducible. "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. " Are you sure you're using the latest Bootstrap 5 beta 3?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I was working in Bootstrap 4 instead of 5. A simple upgrade fixed the problem. I spoke with a fellow developer who recognized it right away.

Answer (score -1):

The reason a border is not shown is that at the markup level, className is not a valid attribute for an element classes definition. Here changing it to *class* corrects the issue:

```
<h2 class="p-3 border border-3">Instruments</h2>
```

Please see working example [here](https://codepen.io/ormasoftchile/pen/ExZqRjo).

Comment: Are you saying Bootstrap doesn't recognize 'className' but only 'class'? If so why is bootstrap working in the rest of my app? Thanks.

Comment: Not a bootstrap thing. React utilizes the className property (note that it exists but it's a DOM property, not an HTML attribute). React renders the class attribute. The reason it works on the rest of your app is up to your implementation. Maybe this snippet you copied is being passed as content without react processing.